# NextJS API directing to index.js file instead of [id].js

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

I'm setting up an API in NextJS. Currently, I have a folder of routes /classes. In this folder, I have index.js and [id].js. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ixN.png)

The purpose of /classes/ is to get all the classes in the db or post a new class.
The purpose of /classes/[id] is to get the specific class, edit the class, or delete it. My issue is that when I try to get a class by id, its returning all the classes from the index.js file. Any ideas about what I'm missing?

index.js

```js
if (req.method === 'GET') {
  try {
    console.log('in index get')
    const allClasses = await db.collection('classes').orderBy('name').get()
    const classes = allClasses.docs.map((doc) => {
      return {
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }
    })
    res.status(200).json(classes)
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: error.message
    })
  }
} else if (req.method === "POST") {
  try {
    await db.collection('classes').add({
      ...req.body,
      lastUpdated: new Date().toISOString()
    })
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'New Class Created'
    })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'There was an error adding class'
    })
  }
}
```

[id].js

```js
switch (method) {
  case 'GET':
    try {
      console.log('in id get')
      const classById = await db.collection('classes').doc(id).get().data()
      res.status(200).json(classById)
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: `Class does not exist`
      })
    }

    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    try {
      await db.collection('classes').doc(id).delete()
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Class Deleted Successfully'
      })
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: `Class does not exist`
      })
    }
    break;
  case 'PUT':
    try {
      await db.collection('classes').doc(id).update({
        ...req.body,
        lastUpdated: new Date().toISOString()
      })
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Class Updated Successfully'
      })
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({
        error: `Class does not exist`
      })
    }
    break;
  default:
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${method} Not Allowed`)
    break;
}
```

Comment: What does your API query look like?

Comment: @neilge {{localhost}}/api/classes/?id=DSGY9jjuY43M210uFg1U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment

> {{localhost}}/api/classes/?id=DSGY9jjuY43M210uFg1U

Try doing this instead:

`{{localhost}}/api/classes/DSGY9jjuY43M210uFg1U`